# Is it possible to configure kerberos authentication in SQL server express editions?

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

Is it possible to configure kerberos authentication in SQL server express editions ?

Answer (score 0):

`Kerberos` is `network` authentication protocol, it has nothing to do with `SQL Server` editions.

Maybe you are interested in how to setup `Kerberos Authentication` on your (Windows) server, you can find it here: [Set Up Kerberos Authentication](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/8-1/globalprotect-admin/authentication/set-up-external-authentication/set-up-kerberos-authentication)

Or maybe your question is how to register `SPN` for `SQL Server`, please refer to this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlupdates/2014/12/05/sql-server-kerberos-and-spn-quick-reference/

Finally, if your question is "does `setspn` utility check for any edition" the answer is no, `setspn` has no idea about editions it just register `SPN`.

Additional reading: [Register a SPN for SQL Server Authentication with Kerberos](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2955/register-a-spn-for-sql-server-authentication-with-kerberos/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed info. Now I understood clearly. Can you please check what I am missing in the below link. I am trying to connect to my SQL server via kerberos but I cant. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55120598/connecting-sql-server-in-java-via-kerberos-authentication

Comment: The error in that post isjava error, NOT SQL Server error. Anyway, take a look here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-kerberos-authentication-jdbc/td-p/54315 itsays "This issue occurs when the jce jars are not up to date on the client machine and not able to use the encryption key provided by Kerberos kdc"